# React Switch const

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some problems with React Switch. I'm trying to make layout inside layout.
So as you already know this code is working fine.

```
import React from "react";
import {Redirect, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import asyncComponent from "util/asyncComponent";

const Dashboard = ({match}) => (
  <Switch>
    <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}/`} to={`${match.url}/dasboard`}/>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/crm`} component={asyncComponent(() => import('./GamePanel/index'))}/>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/link`} component={asyncComponent(() => import('./Servers'))}/> </Switch>
);

export default Dashboard;
```

And now inside this code I have to define const isAuthenticated and to add layout, and I'm doing like this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Menu } from "antd";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { Redirect, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import asyncComponent from "util/asyncComponent";

const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;
const MenuItemGroup = Menu.ItemGroup;

class Servers extends Component {
    state = {
        current: 'News',
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log('click ', e);
        this.setState({
            current: e.key,
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;
        const { match } = this.props;

        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            return <Redirect to="/home" />;
        }

        return (
            <Col span={24}>
                <Menu
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                    selectedKeys={[this.state.current]}
                    mode="horizontal"
                >
                    <Menu.Item key="News">
                        <Link to="/GamePanel/News"><i className="icon icon-alert gx-text-white" /> News</Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="Servrs">
                        <Link to="/GamePanel/Servers"><i className="icon icon-widgets gx-text-white" />Servers</Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="Billing">
                        <Link to="/GamePanel/Billing"><i className="icon icon-pricing-table gx-text-white" />Billing</Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="Support">
                        <Link to="/GamePanel/Support"><i className="icon icon-chat-bubble gx-text-white" />Support</Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="Logs">
                        <Link to="/GamePanel/Logs"><i className="icon icon-plain-list-divider gx-text-white" />Activity Logs</Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                </Menu>

                <Switch>
                    <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}/GamePanel`} to={`${match.url}/GamePanel/News`} />
                    <Route path={`${match.url}/GamePanel/Servers`} component={asyncComponent(() => import('./Servers'))} />
                </Switch>
            </Col >
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null
    };
};
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Servers);

But I can see only layout and nothing inside it. I think it's problem with match const, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

do your redirection at the Dashboard component instead of Servers

Here's the example

```
const Dashboard = ({match, isAuthenticated}) => (
  <Switch>
  <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}/`} to={`${match.url}/dasboard`}/>
  <Route path={`${match.url}/crm`} component={asyncComponent(() => import('./GamePanel/index'))}/>
  <Route path={`${match.url}/link`} 
    component={isAuthenticated ? asyncComponent(() => import('./Servers')) :
    <Redirect to="/home" />} /> 
</Switch>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
     isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(Dashboard);
```

and remove redirect from your Servers component